# How to fix infinite loop in simple C++ function?

Tags: c++, infinite-loop

I'm a beginner in C++ and the code is part of an assignment. I'm having problem with the program infinite looping. I know the infinite loop occurs in sequence(n), but I don't understand why it is infinite looping. I've evaluated the process step by step but I seem to be missing something.

Ex: of a problem I am facing: n = 7, sequence prints: 7 22 22 22 22 22

```
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

// next(n) returns the value that follows n in the hailstone sequence.
// Example: next(7) = 22, next(22) = 11, etc.
// Since the hailstone sequence ends at 1, n is required to be > 1.

int next (int n)
{
  while (n > 1)
  {
    if (n%2 == 0)
    {
      return n/2;
    }
    else
    {
      return 3*n+1;
    }
  }
  return 1;
}

// sequence(n) executes next(n) in a loop to print the next integer(s)
// in the hailstorm sequence, starting from n until ending with 1.

void sequence(int n)
{
  int nextNum = n, x = next(nextNum);
  while (nextNum > 1)
  {
    printf("%i", nextNum);
    nextNum = x;
    break;
  }
  if (nextNum == 1)
  {
    printf("%i", 1);
  }
}

int main()
{
  int n;
  printf("Enter n: ");
  scanf("%i", &n);

  sequence(n);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
while (nextNum > 1)
{
  printf("%i", nextNum);
  nextNum = x;
  break;
}
```

Here, `x` never changes. Consequently, `nextNum` also never changes. This makes the loop either to execute indefinitely or not at all.

Did you mean to call `next()` *inside* the body of the loop, not *outside*?

Also note that `while (n > 1)` in `next()` is a no-op, given that the body of the loop always `returns`.

Comment: That line should be equivalent to nextNum = next(nextNum), how is it that nextNum does not change when next() returns a value?

Comment: @MTee *but it  isn't*. Just because you put `x = next(nextNum)` on the declaration and *initialization* of `x` doesn't mean everywhere `x` appears henceforth is equivalent to substituting the expression `next(nextNum)`. `x` isn't some preprocessor macro. It's a variable.

Comment: Ah this is a great insight. You might think that the line `x = next(nextNum);` just above the `while` statement might mean "every time I reference x I want it to be next(nextNum)", but that's not the case! You merely say that you *initialize* `x` with the value of `next(nextNum)`. From that point on, `x` will *always* be that value that you first initialized it with, unless you change it to something else. The important thing is that `=` does **not** mean equality, it means **assignment**.

Comment: Yes! Thanks for the reminder. I did mean for that line to be inside the **while** loop.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly as @NPE suggests about the not changing value of **nextNum** in while loop. You can simply assign value of nextNum directly without using a variable x.

Second thing is that Why are you using **break** statement in the loop.
 You can write as follows:-

```
while (nextNum > 1)
 {
   printf("%i", nextNum);
   nextNum = next(nextNum);
 }
```

Now **nextNum** will have new value in every iteration of loop. 
Hope this will help you. :-)

Comment: Sorry, the **break** statement was there so I could actually see the outputs in the terminal. Also, my professor discourages callbacks in loops which is why I had **nextNum** in variable **x** initially.

Comment: It's a good practice to keep callbacks outside the loop. But here your loop condition depend upon that callback so you have to put that in the loop.

Comment: @M Tee break statement is not meant to see the outputs on the terminals, use print commands for that.
**break** statement is use to terminate the looping, so if you put **break** in this loop only one iteration will work.

Answer (score -1):

You could actually use this code instead which generates the hailstone sequence.

```
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int n;
  printf("Enter n: ");
  scanf("%i", &n);

  printf("%i\t",n);  
  while(n>1)
  {
  if(n%2==0)
  {

      n=n/2;
  }
  else
  {

      n=(3*n)+1;
  }

  printf("%i\t",n);

}

  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Bad answer. Other improving their cut and paste skills, what does the OP learn from this?  At least explain what you did and why.

Comment: I have specific guidelines to follow so I won't be using that. Thanks tho.

Comment: Well now what is there to understand in this code.It runs a loop from n until n becomes 1 .The value of n is changed inside the loop.After the new value of n is generated,it is printed to the console.